# Swing Frame to change content

Tags: java, swing

Im having difficulty to make different screens for the user without using tab panels. In Netbeans I have created Swing Frame, and after a user signs in, how to refresh the page so sign in screen content is replaced with different screen or JPanel or JTabbedPanel? Should I create in GUI package, main Swing Frame and then some other Swing Frames so then the main Swing Frame to show different content depending on the user's action could use frames or panels from other Swing Frames?

Comment: [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution:

- Use mutiple classes extending JPanel which each represent a specific "phase" of the application.  So if you have a login screen and a main menu, for example, keep these to two separate classes:

  public class LoginPanel extends JPanel
  public class MainScreen extends JPanel
- To add it to the JFrame, call [setContentPane(Container contentPane)].  In this case it'd be: [frame.setContentPane(new LoginPanel)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setContentPane%28java.awt.Container%29)
- Once user credentials are validated, call setContentPane() on the frame with a new MainScreen instance.  Note from the javadoc:

> If you replace the content pane it is recommended you replace it with
>   an opaque JComponent.

Also, to set the JFrame to the preferred size of the content pane, call frame.pack() after adding the new content.

As your amount of different JPanels grows, it probably would be easier to have a "holder" JPanel as the JFrame content pane with no properties, and then you can just remove/add to this instead. This way you can keep constant components that last throughout the app lifecycle like JMenuBar on the JFrame without having to worry about adding it to the JFrame each time.

[1]:

Comment: Action listener event handling code is defined in the same JPanel where action had been performed, right?I assume that action listener in the main frame is not involved if action is performed on JPanel that had been added to main frame, right?  Should I declare methods in the main frame for different phases so after action is performed in one of the JPanels its event handling code will notify the method in main frame asking remove me, perhaps sending additional information to the method argument what kind of action had been performed, so main frame can decide which JPanel should be added?

Comment: @mat2 event handling can happen wherever you want it to happen.  The question is where it *should* go.  If this is a long-term project, I highly recommend Martin Fowler's website as a start for learning about GUI architecture.  The amount of time it'll save you debugging will be worth the time invested in learning this: https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html